# ionic android app crashes with glUtilsParamSize

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cross-platform, ionic-framework

My app crashes while testing in emulator and my device, few times in a day with the message:

> unfortunately app stopped working

Following is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.public279104" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>public</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <!-- <allow-navigation href="*" /> -->
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
  <allow-intent href="*" />
  <access origin="*"/>
```

When I do adb logcat on to my emulator I get following infinite error message with "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found" recurring in between

```
I/chromium( 4146): [INFO:CONSOLE(173)] "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-console/www/console-via-logger.js (173)
D/PluginManager( 4146): exec() call to unknown plugin: Console
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): **** ERROR unknown type 0x0 (glSizeof,72)
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000b44
E/eglCodecCommon( 4146): glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00000bd0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add No Content-Security-Policy meta tag in your file.

< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

< !-- Allow requests to foo.com -->

< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">

< !-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->

< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

< !-- Allow XHRs via https only -->

< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https:">

< !-- Allow iframe to https://cordova.apache.org/ -->

< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">

Please refer https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for more info.